# Listing database data out in an ordered list?

Tags: list

I am creating a catalog for a hotel and in that I have a amenities in the database which consist of all the available amenities  of the hotel, eg breakfast, air conditioning. An example of my database table looks like this :

```
------------------------------------------
hotelID | hotelName | hotelDes | amenities
------------------------------------------
  1     | hotel1    | big room | breakfast, minibar, coffee maker
------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way I can call them and get them to list out in an ordered list like this :

Amenities :  
- Breakfast

- Minibar 
- Coffeemaker

Answer (score 0):

Using **Hibernate**

```
String hql = "SELECT amenities  FROM hotel H  order by amenities ";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq to sql. 
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var Amenities = (from h in db.hotel order by h.amenities select h.amenities).toList();